# using the windows-cmd to start the RGTK2 based GUI

Tags: rscript, rgui

I would like to use the windows-cmd to start R code that was a GUI depending on RGTK2.

For example , named mycode.R

```
   library(RGtk2)
   library(gWidgets2)
   library(gWidgets2RGtk2)
    G.window <- gwindow()
```

this code can be done in the R and Rstudio. However, when i use the window-cmd, the code will fail.

my cmd code:

```
   Rscript.exe  mycode.R
 
   Error in UseMethod(".gwindow"):".gwindow" no applicable method for 'NULL'.
```